# Not able to add new azure function in VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-extensions

I opened my project repo as usual , then I noticed that I can't add new azure function

the + icon disappeared:

[image]

I don't know how to get it back ?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the VS Code and then installing the extension again?

Comment: I have tried to reinstall the extensions but not vs code. same problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272761/azure-function-create-function-command-missing-in-vs-code-2022

Comment: I am now getting the same problem. I was at least able to create a function via the web before, but now even that is disabled

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing the same by downloading the latest July 2022 - version 1.70 we faced the same issue. This might be a bug that is seen in the latest release.

[image]

You can follow the updates from the tickets that I have raised over [Github - Azure Functions Support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3280).

However, as an alternative, you can install the previous stable [June 2022 (version 1.69)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69).