# Azure Function "create function" command missing in VS Code 2022

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

**[update - this appears to be related to [#155030](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155030)]**
I am using VS Code 1.70 and I’ve installed Azure Function Extension v1.7.4 and I don’t see the plus sign on the Workspace section like is shown in the picture I took from the documentation and as result I can’t create an Azure Function project:
From doc:
[image]

Here's what mine looks like.  Notice there is no plus sign that would get me to where I want to go:
[image]

I can deploy an Azure function if I use the plus sign on the Resource section (see image below) and then choose “Create Function App in Azure” but that just creates the Azure Resource but not the project.  Any ideas why my VS Code does not look like the doc says it should so that I can create a function project?
[image]

Comment: What happens if you select `Function App`. It's selected in the first image, but not in the second one.

Comment: Same for me , I don't see the button create new function.

@MarkusMeyer Function App create a remote Function app , but not an Azure Serverless function in the workspace

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, the first image is from the doc and that is what I want to see but am not seeing.  The second image is what I see now and Workspace, when highlighted, just shows the deploy icon (cloud) and the refresh icon (recycle icon), that's it, no plus sign like the first image

Comment: I have the same - seems to be general bug:-(

Comment: As a workaround, I used the "Azure Function: Create Function" from the command pallet (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from the latest July 2022 - version 1.70. For more information, you can follow [Github - Azure Functions Support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3280).

One of the workarounds is to downgrade your VS Code environment to a stable version and this seems working for me.